# Used formula to come back with Month only in text format. Now want to index that month over several months

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a master spreadsheet for our company.  On the first worksheet, I have entered a start date of the job.  On another worksheet, I have reference the start date to the month only: `=TEXT('Cover Sheet'!D3, "mmmm")`. I now want to take the result and index it by month over the 24 months, but I can't seem to figure out the formula to take the result and use it.

Comment: Hii @Grizjohn,, as such nothing wrong with your formula,, furthermore what formula/method U r trying to INDEX data,,, please [edit] your post & share sample data/screen shot ,,, and the  error u r getting !

Comment: The formula above give me the month of when we start a job.  I now want to take that month and index it by 1 month at a time, but with it in text format e.g. July, I cant see to make it work.  Overall example.  Date I enter is 2020-02-11, which is the start date of our job.  On another sheet, I use the formula =TEXT('Cover Sheet'!D3, "mmmm") which give me February in that cell.  I now want to index the month in the next 24 columns by 1.  I am using this row of months to be able to track our housing costs over the duration of the job, by using the starting date and track each month.

Comment: For `2020-02-11` the formula returns correct value `February` ,, furthermore what problem U are facing !! Please be specific and [edit] your post, share some sample data along with expected output, help us to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you wish to create some sort of sequence of the month?

Personally, I prefer to work with numbers whenever possible behind the scenes / until the final display stage (specifically using month function here), but there's also this trick for backwards conversion of month name: https://www.exceltip.com/tips/converting-month-name-to-a-number-in-excel-2010-2013.html

```
=month(datevalue(cell & "1"))
```

Concatenating 1 to the month's name turns it into a formattable date for datevalue, from which the month num is extracted.